# libnet fails to write ip packets

Tags: c, macos, libnet

I'm using a program using libnet, and every time I use it, libnet fails to send any packets.

Specifically, the function that fails is : libnet_write_ip.
It returns -1 on every call.

Any ideas what may cause that ?
I'm on Mac OS X 10.6.4

Thanks so much in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line after the call to libnet_write_ip. Hopefully, the system itself will tell you what is the cause of the function failure.

```
perror("libnet_write_ip");
```

Comment: I get :"Invalid argument". But it's strange, because the program is not mine and is supposed to work.

Comment: If you edit your question and include a bit of code (the call, the setting up of parameters, and anything else relevant) I'm sure a *stacker* with libnet experience will help you find the cause for failure.

Answer (score 0):

According to the libnet manual, the libnet_write_* functions are for internal use only. What you need to use is libnet_write(). This function will write your packets after you've called your libnet_build_* functions.